# How to find user control kept inside another usercontrol from parent aspx page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I have a user control with one grid view and this user control is kept inside another user control.
Now i'm being unable to find the inner user control having gridview from parent aspx page.
I can easily detect the usercontrol which contain the inner user control having gridview.
Please help me how to find usercontrol inside another usercontrol.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourUserControl.FindControl("ControlName you searching for");
```

Comment: Hi all thanks for your answer but there is no property Find in Controls tag.

Comment: I've changed the code slightly, to use FindControl method, hope it helps